# How to calculate the Z-Score for a specific dimension in SQL?

Tags: sql, statistics, teradata

Good afternoon! I am trying to write a query using SQL in Teradata to show me the Z - score for each year in my data. I thought this should be a pretty simple problem, but I keep getting unexpected outputs or errors with each variation I try, and I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I found a few similar posts on here, but I wasn't able to get them working for my specific situation. I'm still learning SQL so please bear with me and let me know if you need any more information. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Formula for Zscore:

z = (x-μ)/σ, where x is the raw score, μ is the population mean, and σ is the population standard deviation

My data is structured like this:
[data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdufO.png)
But has a few more columns with customer info in them but for the purposes of this report I won't be using any of those and only care about the order year, not any of the other date info.

| Order_Year | Order_Count | Zscore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1443553 | -2.175361497 |
| 2019 | 11298753 | 0.313237462 |
| 2022 | 13058147 | 0.757513182 |
| 2020 | 10673440 | 0.155335716 |
| 2021 | 12912660 | 0.720775338 |
| 2018 | 10963180 | 0.228499799 |

```
select 

OrderInfo.Order_Year

,sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count) as Order_Cnt

,(sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count) - AVG(sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count)) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderInfo.Order_Year)) /
    STDDEV_samp(sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count)) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderInfo.Order_Year) as zscore    
    
from ENTERPRISE_STATS.OrderInfo

group by OrderInfo.Order_Year

order by OrderInfo.Order_Year

;
```

| Order_Year | Order_Cnt | zscore |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 10963180 |  |
| 2019 | 11298753 |  |
| 2020 | 10673440 |  |
| 2021 | 12912660 |  |
| 2022 | 13058147 |  |
| 2023 | 1443553 |  |

I tried a couple variations of this and I think it has something to with the sums, but if I remove any of those, it gives me this error:

Executed as Single statement.  Failed [3504 : HY000] Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group.
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.047

STATEMENT 1: Select Statement failed.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information directly in your question preferably as editable text

Comment: You need the group by, what error are you getting with it?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the info. I changed the linked pics to tables for the expected output and what I'm actually getting. 

@Andrew

My issue is that the query I shared is running with no errors, but the output for the zscore column is all NULL and I am not sure why. The table below the query shows the output. 

I thought maybe it had to do with the fact that I am summing the count of orders in the query, but if I just try to calculate on the count like most of the other examples I saw on here (like this:)

Comment: `,((OrderInfo.Order_Count) - AVG(OrderInfo.Order_Count) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderInfo.Order_Year)) /
    STDDEV_samp(OrderInfo.Order_Count) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderInfo.Order_Year) as zscore  `

It gives the error message that I pasted in the main question at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH Order_Cnt AS(

SELECT
OrderInfo.Order_Year
,SUM(OrderInfo.Order_Count) AS Order_Cnt
FROM ENTERPRISE_STATS.OrderInfo
GROUP BY OrderInfo.Order_Year
ORDER BY OrderInfo.Order_Year

)

SELECT
OrderInfo.Order_Year, Order_Cnt,
CAST((Order_Cnt - AVG(Order_Cnt) over())/
STDDEV(Order_Cnt) over () as decimal(10,5)) AS Zscore
FROM Order_Cnt
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! This worked perfectly! I guess I had to use a subquery to get the output looking appropriate! I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: In your initial query when you do OVER (PARTITION BY OrderInfo.Order_Year), the average and standard deviation are being calculated for each row. Average of one number is itself and stddev is zero. Hence you were getting a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nitin88 explained, you just need to remove the PATITION BY in your original query:

```
select 
   OrderInfo.Order_Year

  ,sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count) as Order_Cnt

  ,(sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count) - AVG(sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count)) OVER ()) /
    STDDEV_samp(sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count)) OVER () as zscore    
   
from ENTERPRISE_STATS.OrderInfo

group by OrderInfo.Order_Year

order by OrderInfo.Order_Year
;
```

Re-using the alias:

```
select 
   OrderInfo.Order_Year

  ,sum(OrderInfo.Order_Count) as Order_Cnt

  ,(Order_Cnt - AVG(Order_Cnt) OVER ()) /
    STDDEV_samp(Order_Cnt) OVER () as zscore    
   
from ENTERPRISE_STATS.OrderInfo

group by OrderInfo.Order_Year

order by OrderInfo.Order_Year
;
```